# What exactly is a top-level window in win32 programming?

Tags: windows, winapi, terminology

I don't quite understand what the difference between a window that I create via `CreateWindowEx` and a "top-level" window.

What is a top level window in win32 programming?

Comment: There's also a "top-most" window which is a completely different thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A top-level window is a window that is not a child window, or has no parent window (which is the same as having the "desktop window" as a parent).

Answer (score 9):

The MSDN entry [About Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-windows#parent-or-owner-window-handle) offers the following definition:

> A window that has no parent, or whose parent is the desktop window, is called a *top-level window*.

A more practical explanation is given in the blog post [A window can have a parent or an owner but not both](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100315-00/?p=14613):

> A window can be created as a child window (`WS_CHILD` set) or a top-level window (`WS_CHILD` not set).